# Edit with fake tag "<enough characters to edit>" approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8452247) edit where a tag `<enough characters to edit>` was added to meet the character limit and the edit was approved. The edit did fix some issues with the post but not all. Is adding such tags allowed to fulfill the character limit? If not how should one report about such approved edits?

Comment: Another case of users viewing a suggested edit in rendered view instead of markdown. To a user viewing in the rendered mode it would look a massive visual improvement, but when looking at the markdown you can see that it is a very small edit. Users < 2k should be encouraged to fix as many things as possible when they do edit because other users have to spend time and review votes to approve these edits. Have you notified the user about this question on one of their posts so they can defend themselves?

Comment: @TinyGiant True. No, I have notified the user now.

Comment: @Tiny yes, it's a very small edit -- but that doesn't *stop* it from being a massive visual improvement.

Comment: @TZHX I didnt say that it couldn't be both a massive visual improvement and a very small edit. Users < 2k *should* fix as many things with their edit as possible. I did not say that this user did not fix as many things as they could, but I did imply that this was a waste of votes and would have been picked up by a > 2k user soon enough anyways.

Comment: The edit missed a number of other possible changes, not least removing "Please help! Thanks in advance!"

Comment: Random note that's probably not that useful - `<enough characters to edit>` can behave unpredictably considering possible future changes (it's based on the assumption that there is no "enough" HTML tag). `<!-- enough characters to edit -->` would be (marginally) better (it is, and likely always will be, a comment).

Comment: if editor would remove "Please help! Thanks in advance!" fluff, they wouldn't need senseless trickery around the limit. A week of [meta-tag:edit-ban] could be helpful to learn about stuff like that

Comment: It's surprising that a site built around gameification doesn't realise that this is exactly the outcome expected, with the given rules.

Comment: @Benjol edit bans are part of the game. I for one began playing much better after I got one

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is adding such tags allowed to fulfill the character limit?

That's definitely a no-no. I've checked a few of the users past edits besides that one and it seems that he does this frequently. ex: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8481452) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8454643) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8453416) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8426439) [five](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8396352) [six](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8366942) [seven](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8154713) All seven of those approved.

I have other->mod flagged one of his posts explaining what is happening, so a moderator can notify him that this is not appropriate behavior when editing posts.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought but what about the guys who approve such edits what to do about them?

Comment: @Ram nothing, in most cases. If a mod wants to look into it they will. If you want to , you could go through reviewer's past reviews and see if they make the wrong decision a lot and then flag one of their posts and give concrete examples in your flag message. Other than that, just have to hope the review audit system will catch up to them.

Comment: That is what the audit system is designed for. This would make a good audit though.

Comment: I'll be glad to stop--was just trying to help.  As for removing the "Please help! Thanks in advance!" type of comments, I wasn't aware those were to be deleted.  Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing could be updated to include a relevant bullet to cover this type of material.

Comment: @TonyHinkle The community definitely appreciates your help. See that your fairly new here (2 months) and already have over 100 answers. Definitely appreciate that!  There's a lot of site policies written in the help center and others that get written on metaSO and metaSE. Definitely is confusing and takes a while to get use to. Here's some [reading about edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edits?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) if you want to know more.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I was going to point out that it's probably more covered on the "how to ask" page rather than the editing help pages, ie we don't use "thanks" or "please help" etc here, therefore it's a good idea to edit them out.  But it seems that the [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page doesn't mention not to use that language in the first place...

Comment: If I were editing to fix the markdown processing, I would find a way to better the grammar of the question body or even title. Capitalization, removing excessive please/thank-you. I think the review process should, somehow, require someone to look at both the processed and raw outputs.

Answer (score 7):

In cases where there are more things to fix (as in this case), this is absolutely unwarranted. The reviewers in this case should have clicked *Improve Edit* and removed the fluff.

This may be an unpopular view, but I find that **there are cases where adding such a hidden filler is fine**. I've done that on other sites on the network.

There are two ways this might be necessary:

- Markdown syntax is pretty minimal. There are cases where a single character can make a horribly formatted post into a pretty well formatted post. The shown edit is a good example. I've also seen well formatted code where the first line of the code is only indented by **3** spaces and not 4.
- Since we don't have the *too minor* edit rejection reason anymore, every improvement is welcome. If there is nothing else to improve then it must be possible to successfully submit the edit.

In closing, I take such a hidden filler any day of the year instead of seeing that people are adding "Thanks in advanced" and "Hello" lines.

Comment: Could you not just wait for a >2k user to edit or ping the OP and let him know as well? The ladder being the tougher one to get across but users can learn!

Comment: *there are cases where adding such a hidden filler is fine* => personally, I just find it a bore that such a filler is necessary. On a number of other sites (where I have way less reputation), I'd just like to fix a typo or small thing ("it's" <=> "its" is a frequent error that irks me), but on an otherwise well-written answer the edit is not comprehensive enough...

Comment: Only complaint, the user should have also removed the "Please help! Thanks in advance!"  That would have pushed it over the character limit without having to resort to janky workarounds.

Comment: @Matt There are far too many posts to put your faith to the test and wait until a higher rep user fixes it. I also found that there are far fewer edits on smaller sites. If you are given the tools to fix it, then you shouldn't walk away if you know that it can be made better.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm with you on that one but if the edit was soley to fix something under the character limit there, and no other changes are possible, are many other ways to get it fixed besides trying to game the system is my point. Yes, the reviewer did have to the tools but he was not using properly.